# InitiateSystemShutdown() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python-2.7, winapi

I am trying the win32api import `InitiateSystemShutdown()`. Every time I run my code I get the error:

> TypeError: InitiateSystemShutdown() takes no keyword arguments

Why is this?

Here is my code:

```
import win32api,pythoncom,sys
win32api.InitiateSystemShutdown(computername="HOMEPC",message="bob",timeOut=0, bForceclose=0,bRebootAfterShutdown=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the error is telling you that that function does not take keyword arguments, meaning that you just have to pass the values in as normal arguments without keyword assignment. So try running it like so:

```
win32api.InitiateSystemShutdown("HOMEPC", "bob", 0, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it btw do you happen to know if my syntax is ok?

Comment: Syntax looks correct, let me know if it worked as expected.